# MySQL in CentOS is down, how to fix to start MySQL?

Tags: centos, mysql, centos7

Sorry about the title. I don't know the error code to provide more information.

My website is down by hack. I tried to log in the VPS and backup my source.

But I can't access MySQL. It's show error like:

```
systemctl status mariadb.service
```

[image]

with command: `journalctl -xe`

[image]

Comment: Check the MariaDB logs for the reasons for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Run
systemctl status mariadb.service -l
Command. This will show the status in detail along with error description.
Please post above command output which will help us find root cause and assist you quickly.